# ActiveMQ 5.8 / XMPP Federation (Support for dialback?)

Tags: xmpp, activemq-classic, federation

I'm trying to set up XMPP federation between a Cisco UCM platform and ActiveMQ 5.8. (Would like to consume XMPP messages over JMS). I've verified XMPP is set up on ActiveMQ by attaching to it with iChat, and have sent messages through it that arrive on a JMS topic.

Cisco Federation, however, is not working. I'm seeing the following in the ActiveMQ logs, and I'm not sure where to go with this. I see dialback classes in the xmpp jar files in ActiveMQ..

```
2013-08-27 11:48:29,789 | DEBUG | Creating new instance of XmppTransport | org.apache.activemq.transport.xmpp.XmppTransport | ActiveMQ Transport Server Thread Handler: xmpp://0.0.0.0:61222
2013-08-27 11:48:29,796 | DEBUG | XMPP consumer thread starting | org.apache.activemq.transport.xmpp.XmppTransport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.67.55.53:50750@61222
2013-08-27 11:48:29,800 | DEBUG | Sending initial stream element | org.apache.activemq.transport.xmpp.XmppTransport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-106
2013-08-27 11:48:29,801 | DEBUG | Initial stream element sent! | org.apache.activemq.transport.xmpp.XmppTransport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-106
2013-08-27 11:48:29,852 | DEBUG | Unmarshalled new incoming event - jabber.server.dialback.Result | org.apache.activemq.transport.xmpp.XmppTransport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.67.55.53:50750@61222
2013-08-27 11:48:29,852 | WARN  | Unkown command: jabber.server.dialback.Result@6b7acfe1 of type: jabber.server.dialback.Result | org.apache.activemq.transport.xmpp.ProtocolConverter | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.67.55.53:50750@61222
2013-08-27 11:48:59,864 | DEBUG | Unmarshalled new incoming event - org.jabber.etherx.streams.Error | org.apache.activemq.transport.xmpp.XmppTransport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.67.55.53:50750@61222
2013-08-27 11:48:59,864 | WARN  | Unkown command: org.jabber.etherx.streams.Error@69d2b85a of type: org.jabber.etherx.streams.Error | org.apache.activemq.transport.xmpp.ProtocolConverter | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.67.55.53:50750@61222
2013-08-27 11:48:59,865 | DEBUG | Unmarshalled new incoming event - org.jabber.etherx.streams.Error | org.apache.activemq.transport.xmpp.XmppTransport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.67.55.53:50750@61222
2013-08-27 11:48:59,865 | WARN  | Unkown command: org.jabber.etherx.streams.Error@94552fd of type: org.jabber.etherx.streams.Error | org.apache.activemq.transport.xmpp.ProtocolConverter | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.67.55.53:50750@61222
2013-08-27 11:48:59,865 | DEBUG | XMPP consumer thread starting | org.apache.activemq.transport.xmpp.XmppTransport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///10.67.55.53:50750@61222
2013-08-27 11:48:59,866 | DEBUG | Transport Connection to: tcp://10.67.55.53:50750 failed: java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
```